# Add a dimension to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am iterating a Pandas DataFrame object `mw_alerts`. It contains SHA1 hashes of Malware files from an AV.

```
for i, alert in mw_alerts.iterrows():
    print alert[u'sha1_hash']
```

Now in the loop I make an API request to a service.

```
API_URL = service_url + alert[u'sha1_hash']
r = requests.post(API_URL, headers=HEADERS)
response = r.json()
```

I want to add the `dict response` as a column to the DataFrame object. However it has got 100s of fields as well. Is there a way to make a multi dimensional DataFrame,  to have a relationship like `alert[u'sha1_hash'] -> response[u'description']`? So that I would know that I am looking into a sub table of each alert, which has infos from my service?

I want to avoid having to search though the column. It's much easier to use labels.

Comment: have you considered using a [multi-index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with it, yet.